# How to design loadprofile in performance testing using loadrunner?

Tags: performance, loadrunner

There is no NFR data in my project and no performance testing has ever been performed.
data given is there are 136 concurrent users during peak hours and how many time times each activity has been done during the peak hours.

How to design load profile in  performance testing

Answer (score 0):

Go to the HTTP logs for an objective view of session duration, users online blocked by session duration length, and hourly hits on unique pages tied to business processes.

Make the business sign off on your analysis and own it.  As QA, you cannot both own the creation of the requirement and the assessment of the requirement, particularly since the requirement was absent from the guidance provided to development.   Otherwise, no matter what you discover development, ops, architecture will claim your test is wrong because your assumptions don't match theirs.

Comment: Thanks James.I am able to understand now.